# How to print to the screen from MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

```
.text
emitchar:   

lui $t0,0xffff
polling:
lw  $t1,8($t0)  
andi    $t1,$t1,0x0001
beq $t1,$zero,polling
sw  $a0,0xc($t0)    

.data
```

I was told this is how to do it but when I run the simulator with the display and keyboard add in I still get not output on the screen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know a thing about MARS or about MIPS in general, but (1) the memory-mapped I/O seems to have been introduced in MARS version 3.5 in 2008; is it possible you have a really really old version?, (2) have you arranged for your `emitchar` routine actually to be called, and what's in `$a0` when it is?, and (3) what's supposed to happen at the end of `emitchar`? Shouldn't you be returning or halting or exiting or something of the sort?

Comment: emitchar is going to be called throughout my program and it is just supposed to print a character to the display portion of the simulator. $a0 is supposed to hold a character.

Comment: Right. So, how are you calling it when you test it, and shouldn't there be a `jr $ra` or something at the end?

Comment: in my assignment it says that it should not return anything. Are you saying that i should load the address of a letter into $a0 at the beggining?

Comment: That's not what he's saying. Ask yourself this: what happens after the `sw`? Where does the code go next?

Comment: the code doesnt go anywhere. does it need to go somewhere to print it to the screen

Comment: Right. Though, actually, I *am* also asking: when you call this, what are you putting in $a0 and how?

Comment: By "where does the code go next?" Jeff means: after the simulated CPU has executed the `sw` instruction, what does it do next? It will attempt to execute the next instruction in memory. What is that? Is it some random uninitialized data, or what? -- Whether this makes a difference to whether the character you've written to the memory-mapped I/O ever reaches your display in the simulator, I don't know. Quite possibly not; have you tried the suggestion in Jeff E's answer?

Comment: yep, its working, i am trying to understand how to convert the $a0 to ascii still. thanks for your help guys. i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you click "Connect to MIPS" in the Keyboard window after starting your code? From the Help button:

> IMPORTANT NOTE: The Transmitter Controller Ready bit is set to its initial value of 1 only when you click the tool's 'Connect to MIPS' button ('Assemble and Run' in the stand-alone version) or the tool's Reset button!  If you run a MIPS program and reset it in MARS, the controller's Ready bit is cleared to 0!  Configure the Data Segment Window to display the MMIO address range so you can directly observe values stored in the MMIO addresses given above.

Comment: i am not sure what you mean. how can i configure the data segment window?

Comment: At the bottom of the data segment window, you can change the memory range to MMIO so you can see the contents of the 0xFFFF0000 range of memory. But this is optional. The point is that you have to click 'Connect to MIPS' in the keyboard window. This makes the code work for me.

Comment: Oh cool, ya i noticed that it has the ascii value of the letter that is supposed to be printed. Why is not printing to the display simulator?

Comment: The ASCII value needs to be in `$a0` before you do your `sw`. With the code you posted it'll just be 0, which won't print anything. This looks like a subroutine so I would expect `$a0` to be passed by the caller, but if you want to manually do it for the purpose of debugging, put an instruction somewhere to populate `$a0`: `li $a0, 0x41` -- this is the ASCII value for 'A'.

Comment: okay, sorry im really dumb. i still do not quite understand because shouldnt the simulated keyboard put it in the acsii for me?

Comment: No. It expects that the value given to it will already be in ASCII.