# Polling I/O (MIPS)

Tags: io, mips, polling

I am attempting to write a program in MIPS that uses polling to read a character from the keyboard and then displays it using the builtin Keyboard and Display MMIO Simulator. Unfortunately, I am having trouble grasping the concept behind the registers used and the control bits, but have been trying to figure it out from examples online.

Here is what I have written so far:

```
            .data

            .text
            .globl main

main:
            .eqv    RCR 0xffff0000      # Receiver Control Register     (Ready Bit)
            .eqv    RDR 0xffff0004      # Receiver Data Register        (Key Pressed - ASCII)
            .eqv    TCR 0xffff0008      # Transmitter Control Register  (Ready Bit)
            .eqv    TDR 0xffff000c      # Transmitter Data Register     (Key Displayed- ASCII)

keyWait:    lw      $t0, RCR
            andi    $t0, $t0, 1
            beq     $t0, $zero, keyWait

            lb      $a0, RDR
```

What I believe is happening here is that `keyWait` continues to loop until the ready bit is set to 1 (*), and then the ASCII value of the key is stored in `$a0`. Is this correct?

If this is correct, how can I then print the character on the display using the same polling technique with the TCR and TDR?

*I don't understand why this is needed to be checked with the `andi` operation - if `$t0` is 1 (or 0), it is `and`ed with 1, which equals 1 (or 0), which is then stored in `$t0`? So the value of `$t0` stays as it was prior to this operation regardless?

**EDIT**

Here is my attempt at passing the key pressed data to the display.

```
                .data

                .text
                .globl main

main:
                .eqv    RCR 0xffff0000      # Receiver Control Register     (Ready Bit)
                .eqv    RDR 0xffff0004      # Receiver Data Register    (Key Pressed - ASCII)
                .eqv    TCR 0xffff0008      # Transmitter Control Register  (Ready Bit)
                .eqv    TDR 0xffff000c      # Transmitter Data Register (Key Displayed- ASCII)

keyWait:        lw      $t0, RCR
                andi    $t0, $t0, 1
                beq     $t0, $zero, keyWait

                lbu     $a0, RDR

displayWait:    lw      $t1, TCR
                andi    $t1, $t1, 1
                beq     $t1, $zero, displayWait

                sb      $a1, TDR

                li      $v0, 11
                syscall 

                j       keyWait
```

This is just a test program which should print the character on the MMIO Display Simulator, and also in the console within MIPS. It is doing the latter, but not on the display simulator. In the display simulator, `Cursor:` is incrementing each time a key is pressed, but nothing is being printed. What am I missing?

Comment: What if another bit is set in RCR?  That's why you need the `andi`.

Comment: Oh ok, makes sense. It didn't even cross my mind that it would be set to any other bit as it is done automatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably didn't click "Connect to MIPS".

See this answer: [How to print to the screen from MIPS assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325970/how-to-print-to-the-screen-from-mips-assembly)

When I was testing I've found that if you stop simulation, reload your program, you probably have to click on "Disconnect from MIPS" and then "Connect to MIPS" again (i.e. toggle it a bit)

Also, a *bug*: The data from `RDR` is in `$a0`, but you are storing into `TDR` from `$a1`

From the link, notice that the *style* is slightly different than yours. In the link, they use offsets from a base register rather than hardwiring the addresses. This is much more usual for devices [in device drivers in the real world], particularly if the base address of the device could be configured/changed.

Also, in `mars`, if you look at the actual low level instructions generated from the pseudo-ops in the hardwired vs. base register versions, the base register version is more compact (i.e. fewer injected `lui` insts)

So, I've restyled your code to use a base register:

```
    .data

    .eqv    MMIOBASE    0xffff0000

    # Receiver Control Register (Ready Bit)
    .eqv    RCR_        0x0000
    .eqv    RCR         RCR_($s0)

    # Receiver Data Register (Key Pressed - ASCII)
    .eqv    RDR_        0x0004
    .eqv    RDR         RDR_($s0)

    # Transmitter Control Register (Ready Bit)
    .eqv    TCR_        0x0008
    .eqv    TCR         TCR_($s0)

    # Transmitter Data Register (Key Displayed- ASCII)
    .eqv    TDR_        0x000c
    .eqv    TDR         TDR_($s0)

    .text
    .globl  main
main:
    li      $s0,MMIOBASE            # get base address of MMIO area

keyWait:
    lw      $t0,RCR                 # get control reg
    andi    $t0,$t0,1               # isolate ready bit
    beq     $t0,$zero,keyWait       # is key available? if no, loop

    lbu     $a0,RDR                 # get key value

displayWait:
    lw      $t1,TCR                 # get control reg
    andi    $t1,$t1,1               # isolate ready bit
    beq     $t1,$zero,displayWait   # is display ready? if no, loop

    sb      $a0,TDR                 # send key to display

    li      $v0,11
    syscall

    j       keyWait
```

I did a little "fancy footwork" with the `.eqv` above. In the general case, even though it's a bit more verbose, it may be clearer to do:

```
    .eqv    RCR         0x0000

    lw      $t0,RCR($s0)            # get control reg
```

Comment: That's a lot cleaner, thank you. I had pressed "Connect to Mars", but I think that my issues were, obviously, loading from `$a1` instead of `$a0`, and also how I was writing my registers as `0xffff0000`, instead of just `0x0000`. This is my first real experience of using addresses written in Hex

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, your _only_ bug was the `a0/a1` thing. I tested an intermediate version with just that fix and it worked. I added the offset version as an FYI because it handles the case where you have _two_ controllers (e.g. two disk controllers) or only get the base address from [on a PC] plug-n-play probing. If you notice, the offset approach is similar to the method used in the _MIPS linked list_ link in your previous question to implement a `struct`